# Python regex - Find and count char sequence

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find (and count) a sequence of joined or separated chars, like this : "abc"  ("b" must follow "a" and "c" must follow "b". Case insensitive)

```
"A big duck!" -> the pattern should be matched once. 
"A big duckabc!" -> The pattern should be matched twice.
```

The more I read about regex, the less I know. Is this a matter of using lookahead?

Comment: I think you are looking for `a.*b.*c` and yes, inside a lookahead: `(?=a.*b.*c)`

Comment: is think it's three for second case? `A big duc`, `A big duckabc`, `abc`

Comment: `a.*?b.*?c` are looking for the closest `b` to `a` and `c` to `b`, while `(?=(a.*b.*c))` will return `A big duckabc` and `abc` for the second string. Also, dot matching pattern allows `a` after `b` (before `c`).

Comment: I found that the regex "a.*?b.*?c" serves my purpose. What's the difference between this regex and the lookahead (?=) ?

Comment: If you need overlapping matches for the closest `a..b...c`, you may use Tobias' regex within a lookahead, just as I showed in my previous comment. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cA7xS8/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Even with a lookahead, overlapping matches are not handled perfectly (or at least, not as one might expect), e.g. `re.findall("(?=(a.*?b.*?c))", "aaabc")` will return three matches, even though there are only one b and c. No idea how to fix this, though...

Comment: It is expected. All depends on what you mean by overlapping. There are 3 chunks: `aaabc`, `aabc` and `abc` as the regex engine processes the string position after position, moving from left to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex `a.*?b.*?c` to find `a`, followed by `b`, followed by `c`, with some optional characters in between. The `*?` makes those in-between strings non-greedy (otherwise you would get only one match for the second example).

```
>>> p = "a.*?b.*?c"
>>> re.findall(p, "A big duck!", flags=re.I) # re.I == ignore case
['A big duc']
>>> re.findall(p, "A big duckabc!", flags=re.I)
['A big duc', 'abc']
```

You can also construct that regex from the characters you want to join:

```
>>> chars = "abc"
>>> p = ".*?".join(chars)
```

To get the number of matches, just get the `len` of the result list.

---

Note: This does *not* handle overlapping matches, i.e. `re.findall(p, "aaabbbccc", flags=re.I)` will return only one match. Please clarify whether this is an issue.

Comment: This should fail if the input is `"Aabbcc big duckabc!"`.. I should go with Wiktor's regex..

Comment: @AvinashRaj I guess that depends on how overlapping matches should be handled. The question is not very clear in this regard. I added a notice to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I don't need to handle overlapping matches.